# CSS Animations using libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

so apologies that there are similar questions to this. I've done my best to look so any help would be appreciated.

I'm using a new library of animations from [Animista](http://animista.net) to animate certain elements on a practice site.
I have no issues with animating elements as the page loads but I'm not sure how to go about getting them to trigger as they become visible like is common on so many sites nowadays.

Take this example;

```css
.bounce-in-top {
 -webkit-animation: bounce-in-top 1.1s both;
         animation: bounce-in-top 1.1s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-500px);
            transform: translateY(-500px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  38% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-65px);
            transform: translateY(-65px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  72% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  81% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-28px);
            transform: translateY(-28px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
            transform: translateY(-8px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
@keyframes bounce-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-500px);
            transform: translateY(-500px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  38% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-65px);
            transform: translateY(-65px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  72% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  81% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-28px);
            transform: translateY(-28px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
            transform: translateY(-8px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}

.trigger {
  /* The plan was to add this to all elements and then trigger animations each time the class is in the viewport*/
}
```

```html
<h1 class="bounce-in-top trigger">Page title, animates on load</h1>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


<h2 class="bounce-in-top trigger">Lower down, should animate when visible</h2>
```

The animation is applied to both header 1 and header 2 but the header 2 animation runs before the user sees it.

```css
.bounce-in-top {
 -webkit-animation: bounce-in-top 1.1s both;
         animation: bounce-in-top 1.1s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-500px);
            transform: translateY(-500px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  38% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-65px);
            transform: translateY(-65px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  72% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  81% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-28px);
            transform: translateY(-28px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
            transform: translateY(-8px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
@keyframes bounce-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-500px);
            transform: translateY(-500px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  38% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-65px);
            transform: translateY(-65px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  72% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  81% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-28px);
            transform: translateY(-28px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
            transform: translateY(-8px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}

.trigger {
  /* The plan was to add this to all elements and then trigger animations each time the class is in the viewport*/
}
```

```html
<h1 class="bounce-in-top trigger">Page title, animates on load</h1>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


<h2 class="bounce-in-top trigger">Lower down, should animate when visible</h2>
```

I'd use some sort of query selector so each time an element to be animated would appear it should then run its animation.

Any help and working code would be more than appreciated because I cannot find how to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is track the scrolling state of the page, and start the animation if the scrolling position is superior to a certain value, and then change the animation value of CSS by using Javascript.
A simple example would be like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style> 
    #header2 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: none 1s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
        animation: none 1s infinite;
    }
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        from {left: 0px;}
        to {left: 200px;}
    }


    @keyframes mymove {
        from {left: 0px;}
        to {left: 200px;}
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="header1" style="height: 1200px;">This is first paragraph</h1>
    <br>
    <h1 id="header2">This is second paragraph</h1>

    <script>
        let myHeader2 = document.getElementById("header2");
        window.setInterval(checkScrollingPosition, 200);

        function checkScrollingPosition(){
            console.log(window.scrollY)
            if (window.scrollY > 200){
                //starting animation if scrollPosition > 200
                console.log("starting animation...")
                startAnimation()
                return;
            }

        }

        function startAnimation(){
            myHeader2.style.animation = "mymove 5s 1"
            myHeader2.style.WebkitAnimation = "mymove 5s 1"
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Depending of what you want to do, may be you could replace the threshold value to a certain percentage of the height of the page. For this just research the differents ways to get the scrolling state of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). It makes it possible to check if the elements are in view of the user and call a function when that happens.

In the `InterSectionObserver` you call a function which will loop over all of the elements that have come in or out the view. In that function you can check each individual element to see its current position.

So check if an element is in the view, and if so, add the animation class to it.

Here below I've made a modification of your code. I've created a container around each title so that the title can animate within that container as well as to control the overflow.

So the `.trigger` elements are being watched. When they enter into view they get the class `.bounce-in-top` added to them.

To prevent the animation from suddenly animating from the top I've added a starting position for the `.title` elements. The starting position is always the same as the first keyframe of the animation.

```js
// Create the observer.
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => { // entries is a list of elements that have come in our out of view
  entries.forEach(entry => { // Loop over every single entry
     if (entry.isIntersecting || entry.intersectionRatio > 0) { // Check that an entry has come INTO view.
        entry.target.classList.add('bounce-in-top'); // Add the class to the element.
     }
  });
});

// Select the triggers
const triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');

// Observe the triggers.
triggers.forEach(trigger => {
  observer.observe(trigger);
});
```

```css
/* Create a default begin state */
.title {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-500px);
            transform: translateY(-500px);
}

/* Hide overflow of title container. */
.trigger {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Select title for animation */
.bounce-in-top .title {
 -webkit-animation: bounce-in-top 1.1s both;
         animation: bounce-in-top 1.1s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-500px);
            transform: translateY(-500px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  38% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-65px);
            transform: translateY(-65px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  72% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  81% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-28px);
            transform: translateY(-28px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
            transform: translateY(-8px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
@keyframes bounce-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-500px);
            transform: translateY(-500px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  38% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-65px);
            transform: translateY(-65px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  72% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  81% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-28px);
            transform: translateY(-28px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
            transform: translateY(-8px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
  <h1 class="title">Page title, animates on load</h1>
</div>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="trigger">
  <h2 class="title">Lower down, should animate when visible</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's incredibly detailed and more complex than I expected. I'll look into it for sure :)

Comment: You are welcome. Be sure to do so. If you have any questions, please let me know.